# Ubuntu hangs on boot for ~30 s

Tags: boot

I'm on Linux since 2014 with KXStudio and went to Debian after a while. Now I'm back on Ubuntu (Studio) and I'm really happy how smooth everything works. I got a system crash two months ago with Debian and I don't know the reason. After I installed Ubuntustudio I had no problems, but today there was a 30s delay when rebooting my machine. In the journal I have some entries with the relevant delay (see below). Am I right that the delay is due to a network error?

Sep 18 16:29:23 marco-MS-7817 snapd[713]: autorefresh.go:385:

Or is there any other log file I can check to see what caused that gap? When the system paused I saw the message from fsck on the screen that some things on sda1 got cleaned. I just want to make sure that I don't have an issue with my SSD or so. On the other hand I got this messages also on 11.9. with no delay (see at the bottom).

Thanks in advance
Marco

```
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1048]: Ubuntustudio Controls: Set no_turbo 1
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 ubuntustudio[1051]: 1
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1053]: Ubuntustudio Controls: 0
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1054]: Ubuntustudio Controls: Using performance governor
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1055]: Ubuntustudio Controls: setting performance for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1056]: Ubuntustudio Controls: setting performance for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1057]: Ubuntustudio Controls: setting performance for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1058]: Ubuntustudio Controls: setting performance for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor
Sep 18 16:29:05 marco-MS-7817 root[1059]: Ubuntustudio Controls: Governor set finished
Sep 18 16:29:23 marco-MS-7817 snapd[713]: autorefresh.go:385: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R?max-for>
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: ondemand.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: man-db.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Finished Daily man-db regeneration.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: plymouth-quit-wait.service: Succeeded.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Finished Hold until boot process finishes up.
Sep 18 16:29:25 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 359 (n/a).
```

---

```
Sep 11 15:32:11 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1036]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
Sep 11 15:32:18 marco-MS-7817 systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.178.1.
Sep 11 15:32:20 marco-MS-7817 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Sep 11 15:32:29 marco-MS-7817 snapd[758]: autorefresh.go:385: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R?max-for>
Sep 11 15:32:30 marco-MS-7817 snapd[758]: storehelpers.go:438: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "core18", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gtk-common-themes", "snap-store", "snapd"
Sep 11 15:32:31 marco-MS-7817 snapd[758]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R?max-format=4: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Tempora>
Sep 11 15:32:31 marco-MS-7817 dbus-daemon[707]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Sep 11 15:32:34 marco-MS-7817 lightdm[1126]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `systemd-analyze blame`. It looks like `autorefresh.go` is trying to access the network too early in the startup sequence, before network setup is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. that command was new to me. Here's the output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WCv26jPkwD/  though therer's no autorefresh entry directly. I guess I have to try the command again when it hangs again. Now it was fine again or is it possbile to get these data also from older boots?

Comment: Providing your system release (which tells us the software stack you're dealing with) is also helpful. The more detail provided, the more helpful our advice can be.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. The `-b` option will let you select boots, `journalctl  --list-boots` will show the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know that I can check journal files with the option b to get previous boots. But that parameter does not work with systemd-analyze blame.